# using an image as a pipe in a horizontal nav bar

Tags: xhtml

I have a horizontal nav bar set up, and I have a 2X25 .png that I would like to use as a pipe between the list items.  I figure I need to use border-right, but can't quite get the syntax down.  Could one of you folks help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand. If you want to use `border-right` then you don't need an image.

```
.nav-item { border-right: 2px solid #000; height: 25px; }
```

If you want to use your image, then what you are looking for is `background`.

```
.nav-item { background: url(pipe.png) top right no-repeat; }
```

This places the image in the top right of the background and causes the image to not repeat across the background at all.

Comment: If I want to use it as five pipes between six list items, do I have to mess about with the positioning of each one, or is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: @mrweinerdog No matter which way you do it you will need some way of identifying the last item and reseting the `border` or the `background` on that one item. CSS3 has a selector that will do it (`:last-child` I believe?), otherwise most people just put a `.last` class or similar on the last item or a `.first` on the first item, or both.